# How do I comment out a resource in Asset Pipeline Manifest

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, grails, asset-pipeline

I needed to comment one of the files included in the application.js asset pipeleine manifest file,The way by which one add or include a file to the manifest is through comments in the manifest file . for instance *require bootstrap* means the bootstrap.css or bootstrap.js file is included into the application's css or javascript resources respectively. An example of the file is bellow

```
/*
 * This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.css, which will include      all the files
 * listed below.
 *
 * Any CSS file within this directory can be referenced here using a relative path.
 *
 * You're free to add application-wide styles to this file and they'll appear at the top of the
 * compiled file, but it's generally better to create a new file per style scope.
 *
 *= require main
 *= require mobile
 *= require_self
 */
  console.log("This javascript is also added");
```

I want to comment out the main.css, not removing it, Searched online but did not find any useful information, With asset pipeline just introduced into grails 2.4 adopted from ruby on rails, I think it will be useful to be able to comment out a css or javascript resource in the asset pipeline manifest file.

Comment: You want to comment out the require main?

Comment: Yes Please,  or any other file included

Comment: In your example, just remove the equals sign from the line you want to make a comment. For example `*= require main` becomes `* require main`

Comment: Thanks a lot,I overlooked that.

Comment: Expanded that into an answer. Glad you got it sorted out.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Comments in this CSS manifest are no different than typical CSS comments. either `//` or `/* ... */`. The issue you have here is quite simple, you are overlooking the equals sign on the line you want to comment out. This equals sign indicates to the parser that it should act upon that line, removing the equals sign will turn that particular line into a comment.

So, to comment out `main`:

```
/*
 * This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.css, which will include      all the files
 * listed below.
 *
 * Any CSS file within this directory can be referenced here using a relative path.
 *
 * You're free to add application-wide styles to this file and they'll appear at the top of the
 * compiled file, but it's generally better to create a new file per style scope.
 *
 * NOTICE: the line below does NOT begin with an equals sign, and will be treated as a comment.
 * require main
 *= require mobile
 *= require_self
 */
  console.log("This javascript is also added");
```